# How to add a table to the layout

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have created a table in its own class FileUploaderResultsTable.java, which looks like this:

```
public class FileUploaderResultsTable extends Table
{

    public FileUploaderResultsTable()
    {

        Table resultTable = new Table("Rendering table");
        resultTable.addStyleName("testTable2");
        resultTable.addContainerProperty("Name", String.class, null);
        resultTable.addContainerProperty("Mag",  Float.class, null);

        resultTable.addItem(new Object[]{"Canopus",        -0.72f}, 2);
        resultTable.addItem(new Object[]{"Arcturus",       -0.04f}, 3);
        resultTable.addItem(new Object[]{"Alpha Centauri", -0.01f}, 4);

        resultTable.setPageLength(resultTable.size());
        System.out.println("table created");
    }
```

I have another class FileUploaderComponent.java that, among the other things has a vertical layout that is added to a Window object. I'm trying to display the above table, so in the FileUploaderComponent.java I've created a FileUploaderResultsTable object , like so:

```
public class FileUploaderComponent extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent
{

    ...
    private VerticalLayout myLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    private FileUploaderResultsTable resultsTable = new FileUploaderResultsTable();
    ...
    public void addTable(){
    myLayout.addComponent(resultsTable);
    }

}
```

myLayout then gets added to a new window object in another function. The mechanism works because I'm adding other elements like text fields etc, but for some reasons that table doesn't get added in properly. 
In the DOM I can see that there is a table but it's empty and it doesn't have the class name specified.
To be really honest, ordinarily if I wanted to add a component from another class to a layout I would usually refer to the component as `resultsTable.resultTable` so the object.component syntax rather than just `resultsTable`, but the compiler doesn't like that. SO, is there another way to add a table as a component to the layout or am I just doing something stupid?

Comment: I see you are extending `Table` in your `FileUploaderResultsTable`, and then creating a new copy of `Table` inside it. Why ? As your table extends `Table` it already has all of the functionality. Could it be that when the container calls the functions that return data etc, that the parent `Table` is retuning blank data. There doesn't appear to be any over-ridden methods to get data out of your internal copy.
In other words you could remove all references to `resultTable` in your class.

Comment: I'm extending Table because I will have to lazy load some rows (that's just a dummy table, the real one could be thousand of rows long).
So, you're saying that if I'm extending table I can directly add rows to it without creating a table because extending the class Table already creates one?

Comment: read some tutorials how to work with extended classes in java.

Answer (score 1):

You are using your extended class the wrong way. Try this:

```
public class FileUploaderResultsTable extends Table
{

    public FileUploaderResultsTable()
    {
        setCaption("Rendering table");
        addStyleName("testTable2");
        addContainerProperty("Name", String.class, null);
        addContainerProperty("Mag",  Float.class, null);

        addItem(new Object[]{"Canopus",        -0.72f}, 2);
        addItem(new Object[]{"Arcturus",       -0.04f}, 3);
        addItem(new Object[]{"Alpha Centauri", -0.01f}, 4);

        setPageLength(resultTable.size());

        System.out.println("table created");
    }
}
```

Comment: yes that works. OK, I think I will follow your suggestion and read some extended classes tutorial as clearly I didn't know what I was doing. Can you recommend a good tutorial yourself, or should I just find some on google?

Comment: I thought I'd update this quickly, as I seem to be experiencing a strange problem. So I created the table the way you suggested @d2k2 and it works. The table sits in an another window, some sort of popup, and when I close it and reopen it again (there is a loop that populates the rows) the table is empty. SO, in essence, it works only the first time: is that because the table is created only once since I'm using a class that extends Table?

Comment: the table is only filled on object creation. i dont know how your code look like, so i can not help you with other issues.

Comment: I think I figured that out, I need to 'clear' the table every time I've finished with it, so a `Object.removeAllItems();`, for some reasons that I can't grasp, seems to be doing the job. In my table, I create rows dynamically and then display the table in a new window, which looks like a popup and has a close button. When I close this window the table disappears but it seems that somehow the data in the table is preventing new data from getting loaded...no idea